# Creating snowflake view with no reference table in Terraform

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, terraform-provider-aws

Can someone please confirm if there is a way to create a snowflake view in Terraform with no reference table?

Here's an example,

```
resource "snowflake_view" "view" {
  database = "database"
  schema   = "schema"
  name     = "view"

  comment = "comment"

  statement  = <<-SQL
    SELECT 'FALSE' AS BOOLEAN;
SQL
  or_replace = true
  is_secure  = false
}
```

I tried to run Terraform fmt on this tf code and it returned code 3

Ref : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/latest/docs/resources/view

Answer (score 0):

There is simple workaround if `FROM` clause is mandatory:

```
SELECT 'FALSE' AS BOOLEAN;
<=>
SELECT 'FALSE' AS BOOLEAN FROM dual;
```

Output:

[image]

---

Please note that:

```
EXPLAIN USING TABULAR SELECT 'FALSE' AS BOOLEAN FROM dual;
EXPLAIN USING TABULAR SELECT 'FALSE' AS BOOLEAN;
```

Returns the same query profile:

```
| step | id | parentOperators |  operation  | objects | alias | expressions |
|------|----|-----------------|-------------|---------|-------|-------------|
|      |    |                 | GlobalStats |         |       |             |
|    1 |  0 |                 | Result      |         |       | 'FALSE'     |
|    1 |  1 | [0]             | Generator   |         |       | 1           |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run TF fmt and get a non-zero return code then all it is telling you is that the file is not formatted to the expected standard - not that there is necessarily anything incorrect about the contents.

If you run fmt with the -diff parameter (and/or the -check parameter) it should tell you what issues with the format are